# Substring between two same or different delimiters (when delimiters occur multiple times)

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I need to fetch a sub string that lies between two same or different delimiters. The delimiters will be occurring multiple times in the string, so i need to extract the sub-string that lies between mth occurrence of delimiter1 and nth occurrence of delimiter2. 
For eg:

```
myString : Ron_CR7_MU^RM^_SAF_34^
```

What should i do here if i need to extract the sub-string that lies between 3rd occurrence of '_' and 3rd occurence of '^'?

```
Substring = SAF_34
```

Or i could look for a substring that lies between 2nd '^' and 4th '_', i.e :

```
Substring = _SAF
```

An SQL equivalent would be :
substr(myString, instr(myString, '*',1,3)+1,instr(myString, '^',1,3)-1-instr(myString, '*',1,3))

Comment: What if the 3rd `^` is before the 3rd `_` Having overlapping delimiters is a sign of worried mind. ;)

Comment: Need more information. Could you provide a function signature as you see it being called to perform this operation? Also you mention finding a string between mth delim1 and nth delim2, but your example is about mth delim1 and mth delim2, so what is it you want?

Comment: thx suresh.. that was immensely helpful... i somehow tagged regex along with the question.. dont really know how..

Comment: Lots of missing information. Are your delimiters always single characters? Can there be a case where the first delimiter can appear _after_ the second?

Comment: @Rudi, my bad.. in my example both m and n happen to be the same. i.e. '3'. but in a generic way, i need to fetch a substring between mth occurrrence of delim1 and nth occurrence of delim2

Comment: @fge, the delimiters can be a string with multiple characters as well. and it is possible that the first delimiter can occur after the second. my bad.. i didnt frame the question properly...

Comment: `_(.*?)\^` would find "CR7_MU" and "SAF_34" if that is, what you want.

Comment: @PeterLawrey in that case it should return a null string, no match message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use,

```
public static int findNth(String text, String toFind, int count) {
    int pos = -1;
    do {
        pos = text.indexOf(toFind, pos+1);
    } while(--count > 0 && pos >= 0);
    return pos;
}

int from = findNth(text, "_", 3);
int to = findNth(text, "^", 3);
String found = text.substring(from+1, to);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a solution without regex you can find indexes in your string where your resulting string needs to start and where it needs to end. Then just simply perform: `myString.substring(start,end)` to get your result.

Biggest problem is to find `start` and `end`. To do it you can repeat this N (M) times:

1. `int pos = indexOf(delimiterX)`
2. `myString = myString.substring(pos)` //you may want to work on copy of `myString`

Hope you get an idea.

Comment: +1 regex expects tokens to appear in particular orders, like a syntax.  Having them intermixed is likely to be complicated for one regex.  You could have two regex, one for ^ and one for _ and substring the difference, but using `indexOf(delimiter, fromIndex)` is likely to be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a little method that simply hunts for such substrings between delimiters sequentially, using (as noted) String.indexOf(string);  You do need to decide whether you want all substrings (whether they overlap or not .. which your question indicates), or if you don't want to see overlapping strings.  Here is a trial for such code

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class FindDelimitedStrings {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] test = getDelimitedStrings("Ron_CR7_MU'RM'_SAF_34'", "_", "'");
    if (test != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(" " + (i + 1) + ". |" + test[i] + "|");
        }
    }
}

public static String[] getDelimitedStrings(String source,
        String leftDelimiter, String rightDelimiter) {
    String[] answer = null;
    ;
    Vector<String> results = new Vector<String>();

    if (source == null || leftDelimiter == null || rightDelimiter == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int loc = 0;
    int begin = source.indexOf(leftDelimiter, loc);
    int end;
    while (begin > -1) {
        end = source
                .indexOf(rightDelimiter, begin + leftDelimiter.length());
        if (end > -1) {
            results.add(source.substring(begin, end));
            // loc = end + rightDelimiter.length(); if strings must be
            // returned as pairs
            loc = begin + 1;
            if (loc < source.length()) {
                begin = source.indexOf(leftDelimiter, loc);
            } else {
                begin = -1;
            }
        } else {
            begin = -1;
        }
    }

    if (results.size() > 0) {
        answer = new String[results.size()];
        results.toArray(answer);
    }
    return answer;
}
}
```